# Tinymce load file_browser_callback after init has run

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, tinymce

I want to add support for a file uploader. It is working fine, but i only want it enabled for users who are logged in. The site uses a lot of caching which means it is possible for a logged in user to view the page and it will be cached. Then a non logged in user can be served this same cached page and things break since the file manage code is there, but server side code is blocking it. I already have some code in place that loads the html cache and an ajax query will do some extra stuff if the user is logged in. I want to be able to load the file browser at this point, after tinymce has loaded.

In short terms, how do i add the following to tinymce 4 after it has fully loaded

```
file_browser_callback: mediabrowser
```

In some cases i load tinymce via javascript in order to cache the code for it. I was hoping i could do something like this in response function after the ajax method completes.

```
tinymce.file_browser_callback = "mediabrowser";
if(tinymce.status == "loaded") tinymce.refresh();
```

Comment: Can you just use an ajax call back to the server to see if the user is logged in and then on success, enable it? You're already using ajax so that should be trivial.

Comment: due to how i load tinymce already it makes it a little harder to do this. i have some events tied into tinymces load event that make it tough. i have added a little more to the main question to clarify that i was hoping to be able to do